# How to retrieve all data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple records stored in Firebase like this:

```
-KyEpOpqClj_sE2ktP1

   -Diameter: "200"

   -Height: "3"

   -Literage: "12580.73"

   -Metal: "Stainless Steel"
```

and I want to retrieve the data and display it like this in a ListView.

```
-Diameter: 200
-Height: 3
-Literage: 12580.73
-Metal: Stainless Steel
```

Firebase Database: https://imgur.com/gallery/6HV1Ah4

Comment: Did you tried any code yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("KyEpOpqClj_sE2ktP1");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String value=dataSnapshot.child("Metal").getValue().toString();
      String height=dataSnapshot.child("Height").getValue().toString();
      String diameter=dataSnapshot.child("Diameter").getValue().toString();
      String literage=dataSnapshot.child("Literage").getValue().toString();
  }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


 }
 });
```

If you have multiple children under root then do:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String value=data.child("Metal").getValue().toString();
     //retrieve here
   }
```

Comment: This works but it only displays the data for that child. How would I do this for multiple children?

Comment: instead of `child("KyEpOpqClj_sE2ktP1")` go one layer up @ScottyDooZA

Comment: that gives me NullPointerException and all the strings are null

Comment: @ScottyDooZA you have to query depending on your database... I answered the question that you asked.. I dont have your database

Comment: sorry, I'll add a picture of my Firebase database

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make data model for all these parameters like

```
DataModelClass - Diameter,Height,Literage,Metal
```

And please get it parsed in same way as your data model .

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("KyEpOpqClj_sE2ktP1");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      DataModelClass dataM = (DataModelClass) dataSnapShot;
  }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


 }
 });
```